# How to force Empathy Internet Messaging to change default webcam?

Tags: 11.10, usb, empathy, webcam, default

I just recently bought a new webcam. It is USB powered. For personal reasons, I wish to not use the built in webcam that came with my netbook.

I want to use this new one. I love empathy, it is a great chat client. But, I can't seem to switch my default webcam in empathy from the built in webcam, to the one I just bought.

*So, is there a way to force empathy to use the USB powered webcam, rather than the built in webcam?*

Let's eliminate some options.

1. I tried the gstreamer-properties method, root and normal user. No use.
2. I tried the configuration editor method as-well, trying to manually change web-cam defaults.
3. I also tried blacklisting the built in web-cams driver, but my second web-cam also
   runs off that same driver so that option was pointless because it disabled both web-cams, instead of the one I needed to use.

Comment: You could blacklist the built-in one /etc/modprobe.d ... Then the new one becomes the default.  A way around the problem.

Comment: How would I go around to doing that? Thanks.

Comment: How would I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want I think is udev rules.

I'm on 12.04 so your mileage may vary, but here's an example:
You want to change switch /dev/video1 and /dev/video0. First get the info you need:
`udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/video0)`
`udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/video1)`
Copy both of those huge blocks of text into gedit
Mine looked like this:

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/video4linux/video0':
    KERNEL=="video0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="video4linux"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{name}=="USB2.0 PC CAMERA"
    ATTR{index}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="uvcvideo"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="0e"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{iad_bFirstInterface}=="00"
    ATTRS{iad_bInterfaceCount}=="02"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionClass}=="0e"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionSubClass}=="03"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionProtocol}=="00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="320mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="5064"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="18ec"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="3299"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ef"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="14"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="ARKMICRO"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 PC CAMERA"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="  0mA"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="324"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0302"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="6"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.2.0-22-generic ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:12.2"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:12.2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1002"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x4396"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1043"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x8389"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0320"
    ATTRS{irq}=="17"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,0000000f"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="0"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{companion}==""
    ATTRS{uframe_periodic_max}=="100"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

You're looking for the attributes from lsusb that match your camera:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="firsthalf"
ATTRS{idProduct}=="secondhalf"
```

Then as root you edit your `/etc/udev/rules.d/25-video-device.rules`
That name is relatively arbitrary.  The number has to do with what sets get parsed first, but it pops up in a lot of udev google searches. Let's just use it.

Mine looks like:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18ec", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3298", NAME:="video0", OPTIONS:="link_priority=100"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="090c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c371", NAME:="video2"
```

Save the file

Some sources indicate as root `service udev restart`, but I got a hard lock.  So just reboot with it plugged in.
Now fire up anything that doesn't let you choose a video device.  Since they're probably hard-wired to use /dev/video0, this should "just work".

For whatever reason, at least for me, it won't over-ride and displace the existing video0, it just creates two files(maybe by design).  You could `ln -sf /dev/video1 /dev/video0`.  For me devices I specified this way seem to work. I tested with guvcview.

Congratulations, you just wrote a udev rule to overcome a hard-coded url.

You can specify to run commands at the ends of those udev rules too.

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18ec", ATTRS{idProduct}=="3298", NAME:="video0", OPTIONS:="link_priority=100", RUN+="ln -sf /dev/video1 /dev/video0"

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="090c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c371", NAME:="video2"
```

Now your USB video occupies /dev/video0 and /dev/video1.  You don't lose your built-in either since now it's located at /dev/video2.