# Problem with executing udev rules for olimex's avr-usb-jtag

Tags: udev

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 for programming purposes and recently decided to bring my previous atmel's micro-controller projects from Win to Linux. Namely AVR.

I installed the tool chain all right. It includes: avrdude binutils-avr gcc-avr avr-libc gdb-avr.

To test my connection to the micro-controller I used an olimex avr-usb-jtag programmer. When I plug it in and it is seen as /dev/ttyUSB0 (being an FTDI usb-com chip). The programmer is Atmel JTAGICE compatible.

Now when we try to

```
avrdude -p c128 -c jtag1 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -t
```

And we get

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": Permission denied
```

So far it seems that without root's permissions we can't write nor read from the device. And it proves to be true when we actually try

```
sudo avrdude -p c128 -c jtag1 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -t
```

The response is:

```
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s
avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9781
```

Now I want to enable usual users (like programming IDE's for example) to access the programmer without giving them root permissions. The FIRST QUESTION for me is how to do that better?

I tried the udev approach and wanted the system to distinguish the plugged in device and apply permissions to the device file (ttyUSB0 by default for me). But the only option that worked was making a new file:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/10-usb-avr-jtag.rules
```

It contained

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB*" MODE="0666"
```

This configuration works, but I'm curious why something like this below doesn't work for me at all (the default ttyUSB0 is appearing, no rules are applied to the file)?:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idProduct}=="6001", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", MODE="0666"
```

Any ideas on how to make it work, or why it doesn't work at all?

[Here's my output udevadm](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1026853/)

Comment: I don't have your exact hardware so I can't say for sure...I do have an answer related to udev rules here http://askubuntu.com/questions/118733/how-to-force-empathy-internet-messaging-to-change-default-webcam/121618#121618  ... Maybe if you do that first part of my answer `udevadm info` whatever and put the output on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add a link to it

Comment: Sure thing, here's the output together with the command: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1026853/

Comment: Thank you )
It seems that considering the googled answers is not a good option, I never used udev so close before and everywhere on the Net they write "SYSFS" or "ATTR" don't know why I didn't try copying the output directly.
Now the correct working string is:

    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", NAME:="ttyUSBavr", MODE="0666"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the former works, I suspect the latter should read

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", MODE="0666"
```

Comment: No problem.  We're here b/c we like to help.  This came up in chat the other day as well, so I thought looking at it was even more worthwhile