# How to fix this problem, where sometimes /dev/video0 becomes automatically /dev/video1 as a result other apps cant read

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, drivers, bash, video

I have one camera USB which on connect makes a place as /dev/video0, now using other applications while its reading /dev/video0 works fine, after some time like couple of hours later, automatically the /dev/video0 disappear and it becomes /dev/video1. As a result the same application stop working to capture it because there is no more /dev/video0.

How is it possible to apply a BASH loop to have a clone of /dev/video0 and /dev/video1 always. Like if video0 is lost but video1 is present then the script will clone exactly one another.

Any idea, how to fix it so that we have always /dev/video0 and /dev/video1 clone of any one another?

**Follow up:**

[Well answered too](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118733/how-to-force-empathy-internet-messaging-to-change-default-webcam/121618#121618)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty common, but basically you shouldn't mess with stuff under /dev it's a special file system that gets regenerated causing just the problem your talking about. instead you need to set up a udev rule to make sure your devices are always getting the same name.

[Use this information](https://bugs.launchpad.net/mythbuntu/+bug/310820/comments/5) from comment 5, to setup your rules file.

It's a bit complicated to phase correctly in this site, but basically:

1. Get your device info with `udevinfo -a -p $(udevinfo -q path -n /dev/video0)` for each device.
2. Find something different about the devices
3. Head to /etc/udev/rules.d and make a new rules file (with a low number like 11)
4. modify the file to use your new attribute and give your device a new/static name

It's very complicated, but works quite well.